# WebClient 5.3+ exchange vs exchangeToMono. Extracting cookies and body together

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, lambda, webclient, spring-webflux

I am currently trying to consume a whole request coming back via webClient. I need to be able to read the *body* and the *cookies* that come with it. However I am currently having issues doing both together in one call. Below I have two ways of grabbing the data I want. I am pretty new at using lambdas and webClient. I do realize that exchangeToMono() is the latest method call to return a Mono or Flux because of the possible memory leak found in exchange().
I want to say subscribing() to a return monoBody might help me but so far I have had no luck extracting the data out that way as well. Thank you all for your input.

```
Mono<String> monoBody = webBuilder.build()
                .get()
                .uri(baseURI + "?Level=&pageSize=50&pageNo=&name=&id=&authToken=" + sessionToken)
                .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                .header("authToken", sessionToken)
                .header("x-Token", sessionToken)
                .header("X-token-X", sessionToken)
                .header("Ref", ref)
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class));

 Mono<MultiValueMap<String,ResponseCookie>> monoMap = webBuilder.build()
                .get()
                .uri(baseURI + "?Level=&pageSize=50&pageNo=&unitName=&id=&authToken=" + sessionToken)
                .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                .header("authToken", sessionToken)
                .header("x-Token", sessionToken)
                .header("X-token-X", sessionToken)
                .header("Ref", ref)
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> Mono.fromCallable(()-> clientResponse.cookies() ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to remember about the Reactor API (used by WebClient) is that you are always composing operations into a 'plan' of what to do and then at some point (subscription) you execute the entire plan.

In your case you've found the two methods to get the information you want but with a Reactive stream you can only ever have one type at any point in the stream, so if you need two types of data, you can always compose them into a composite object.

```
record DataWithCookies(MultiValueMap<String,ResponseCookie> cookies, String body){}

...
Mono<DataWithCookies> dataWithCookies =
      webBuilder.build()
                .get()
                .uri(baseURI + "?Level=&pageSize=50&pageNo=&unitName=&id=&authToken=" + sessionToken)
                .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                .header("authToken", sessionToken)
                .header("x-Token", sessionToken)
                .header("X-token-X", sessionToken)
                .header("Ref", ref)
                .exchangeToMono(response -> 
                    response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                            .map(stringBody -> new DataWithCookies(
                                                        stringBody, 
                                                        response.cookies())
                            )
                );
```

I used the [previewed JDK 16 feature "Records" for brevity](https://andrew-flower.com/blog/202011-java-records), but you could use a simple class for `DataWithCookies`.

You now have a Mono that will yield the body along with the cookies.  You might want to even extract that lambda into a private method for readability.

```
                    ...
                    .exchangeToMono(this::extractBodyAndCookies);

...

private DataWithCookies extractBodyAndCookies(final ClientResponse response) {
    return response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                   .map(stringBody -> new DataWithCookies(stringBody, 
                                                          response.cookies())
                   );
}
```

Another option is to use `Tuples.of(stringBody, response.cookies())` which avoids creating another type while still composing the two data.

Comment: Thank you, this sorta of boxing in of the data helped. I was hoping for a easier option other than this way, but I am guessing for now, this will have to be the way its done. Thank you for taking the time to reply.